# Drawing a bijective map with TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to produce a diagram similar to the following (from Wikipedia)

[image: Bijection]

in TiKz.  Now, I thought this would be relatively simple, however, I am having trouble getting the elements (the dots) to be of the correct size and am unsure how to elegantly surround the elements in an ellipse.  My current TiKz code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    shapes,shadows,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[ele/.style={fill=black,minimum size=2pt,circle}, node distance=7pt]
  \node[ele] (a1) {};
  \node[ele] (a2) [below=of a1] {};
  \node[ele] (a3) [below=of a2] {};
  \node[ele] (a4) [below=of a3] {};
  \node[ele] (b1) [right=of a1,xshift=15pt] {};
  \node[ele] (b2) [below=of b1] {};
  \node[ele] (b3) [below=of b2] {};
  \node[ele] (b4) [below=of b3] {};
  \draw[->,thick] (a1) -- (b4);
  \draw[->,thick] (a2) -- (b2);
  \draw[->,thick] (a3) -- (b1);
  \draw[->,thick] (a4) -- (b3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which renders as

[image: Mine]

Can anyone recommend a more elegant means of drawing such a diagram?

Comment: Set `inner sep` in the `ele` style to `0`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,fit,shapes,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[ele/.style={fill=black,circle,minimum width=.8pt,inner sep=1pt},every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=-2pt}]
  \node[ele,label=left:$a$] (a1) at (0,4) {};    
  \node[ele,label=left:$b$] (a2) at (0,3) {};    
  \node[ele,label=left:$c$] (a3) at (0,2) {};
  \node[ele,label=left:$d$] (a4) at (0,1) {};

  \node[ele,,label=right:$1$] (b1) at (4,4) {};
  \node[ele,,label=right:$2$] (b2) at (4,3) {};
  \node[ele,,label=right:$3$] (b3) at (4,2) {};
  \node[ele,,label=right:$4$] (b4) at (4,1) {};

  \node[draw,fit= (a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;
  \node[draw,fit= (b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;  
  \draw[->,thick,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt] (a1) -- (b4);
  \draw[->,thick,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2] (a2) -- (b2);
  \draw[->,thick,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2] (a3) -- (b1);
  \draw[->,thick,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2] (a4) -- (b3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `minimum width=.8pt,inner sep=1pt` to get smaller points

Comment: Any chance explaining this wall of code?

Comment: Why did you hard code the coordinates, for example, `(4,4)`, etc? The OP did not use such hardcoded coordinates. And I think using hardcoded coordinates makes future update much harder. What do you think?


I found another related answer but without hardcoded coordinates [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219968/87876).

Answer (score 1):

[Wallner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56139/tikz-diagram-showing-range-domain-and-co-domain-of-a-function)'s answer was one of the best mapping diagram I have ever seen. I modified his code for your problem

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % draw the sets
    \filldraw[fill=blue!20, draw=blue!60] (-1.5,0) circle (1cm);
    \filldraw[fill=red!20, draw=red!60] (1.5,0) circle (1cm);


    % the texts
    \node at (-1.5,1.5) {$X$};
    \node at (1.5,1.5) {$Y$};

    % the points in the sets (here I just create nodes to use them later on to position
    % the circles and the arrows
    \node (x1) at (-1.5,0.7) {$a$};
    \node (x2) at (-1.5,0.3) {$b$};
    \node (x3) at (-1.5,-0.2) {$c$};
    \node (x4) at (-1.5,-0.7) {$d$};
    \node (y1) at (1.5,0.7) {$1$};
    \node (y2) at (1.5,0.3) {$2$};
    \node (y3) at (1.5,-0.2) {$3$};
    \node (y4) at (1.5,-0.7) {$4$};

    % draw the arrows
    \draw[->] (x1) -- (y4);
    \draw[->] (x2) -- (y2);
    \draw[->] (x3) -- (y1);
    \draw[->] (x4) -- (y3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Mapping diagram of relation $S$}
\end{figure}
```

which produce the mapping below:
[image]