# Function composition table

Tags: mathtools

I want to do a simple function composition table with arrows drawn from different sets to sets. Like textbooks show functions by using "blobs" and arrows emerging from the blobs. Can someone help me build a function composition table for my homework?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219968/194703)? (You can always do a Google **picture** search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com <your term>` and click on promising pictures to get an idea how such things can be done; the above like was obtained with a search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com tikz mapping`.)

Comment: Yes thank you!!

Comment: I'm voting to close as duplicate of the suggested question: [Is there a simpler way of drawing relation maps?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219965/is-there-a-simpler-way-of-drawing-relation-maps)