# One to one function, how to draw in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, graphs, calculations, grouping, mathematics

Here are both set of one to one function. How to make LaTeX coding in figure type:

(x)=0,2,3
(y)=a,b,c

Comment: Do you mean something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Codomain2.SVG or the ones on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection ?

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19987/47927